# Se crashea la App antes de dar permisos (Google Maps API)

Tags: java, android

Tengo puesto en mi aplicación para las `API de Google` (para usar el Maps) y las siguientes líneas de código para que en todos los dispositivos (incluido los superiores a 6.0) puedan dar permisos y que funcione correctamente. El código funciona y sale un cartel pidiendo permiso,le pones "OK" y vuelve a iniciarse dejándote utilizar el mapa.

**El problema es que antes de ese cartel sale un cartel diciendo que la aplicación se ha detenido** y no quiero que dicho cartel salga. ¿Qué falta??

Parte del código donde están los permisos:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    getActivity(), new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1337);
        }
    }
```

Permisos que tengo en el manifest son entre otros:

El de `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` Y `LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE`

**Lo que me salió en el log:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1, PID:
>   6957 java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION at maps.ad.t.c(Unknown
>   Source) at xj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:274)
>   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$‌​zza.setMyLocationEna‌​bled(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(U‌​nknown
>   Source) at –

Actualizado, lo que tengo en el onCreate:

`public class Map_fragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);

    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    getActivity(), new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1337);
        }
    }



    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   // MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapid);
   // mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
   // USO SUPPORTMAPFRAGMENT PORQUE SOLO CON MAPFRAGMENT SE ME CRASHEABA AL VOLVER A ENTRAR AL MAPA!!
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapid);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return v;
}
```

Pero debajo del `if` iba esta línea: `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` y ahora **me da error porque lo del if lo he subido arriba al onCreate**, y se ha quedado colgando esta línea pues le hace falta el checkSelfPermission, cómo lo hago?

Comment: Ya agregaste los permisos al `AndroidManifest` ?

Comment: Los tengo agregados, ese no es el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una razón puede ser que no tengas los permisos definidos dentro del archivo AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Si esto es así lo único que puede estar sucediendo es que la petición de permisos se esta realizando después de tratar de obtener una localización en el mapa :

> ¿ Se me crashea la App antes de dar permisos (Google Maps API)?

, por ejemplo podrías pedirlos al iniciar tu aplicación dentro del método `onCreate()`.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i("Permisos", "Se tienen los permisos!");
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 1337);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Elena, discúlpame, no los había puesto aquí pero sí que los tengo en el Manifest, ese no es el error.

Comment: Mañana pruebo lo de poner el if en el metodo onCreate, que no tengo el móvil aquí, y te comento.

Comment: OK, entonces definitivamente eso podría ser, debes asegurarte primero pedir el permiso =P antes de usarlo.

Comment: Elena, creo que es eso sí, ya no me sale el cartel, lo que pasa que ahora, la línea que tenía debajo que era : ``map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`` me da error porque le hace falta la línea de check permission del ``if`` que hago entonces? pongo de nuevo el ``if`` dentro con los permisos para que me lo acepte? o me va a dar error por tener dos veces los mismos permisos?

Comment: Sí, lo he puesto dos veces y me ha dado error, como hago para poner esa línea correcta?

Comment: he actualizado lo que tengo en el oncreate poniendo el ``if`` que me has dicho que **sí que me ha funcionado** pero esa línea no...