# ¿Cómo poder determinar mi ubicacion ejecutando la aplicacion en un emulador?

Tags: android, android-studio, localización

estoy obteniendo las coordenadas para obtener mi ubicacion justo como se muestra en el siguiente enlace https://expocodetech.com/expo-tips-como-obtener-la-ubicacion-actual-con-el-gps-de-android/

El problema es que en mi Celular fisico funciona correcto, pero en el emulador me cierra la aplicación. El error que me manda es el siguiente:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil, PID: 4835
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.gps_localizacion@2babda9 with Intent { cmp=desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil/.gps_localizacion }: java.lang.SecurityException: "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3314)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
                  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:614)
                  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:887)
                  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:471)
                  at desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.gps_localizacion.onStartCommand(gps_localizacion.java:83)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: En el log parece un problema de permisos, prueba a echarles un vistazo: SecurityException: "network" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission Que la fuerza te acompañe

Comment: En esta pregunta de esta misma web tienes la respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45737/se-crashea-la-app-antes-de-dar-permisos-google-maps-api ¿Duplicado?