# Android no puede solicitar permiso manualmente para Geolocalización

Tags: android, android-layout, geolocalización

El código que tengo está funcionando si habilito la "Ubicación" a mano, pero no me pregunta, cuando está deshabilitada. Les dejo mi código

```
public class UltimoPaso extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private FusedLocationProviderClient client;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(UltimoPaso.this);

.....

btnok_ultimo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UltimoPaso.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UltimoPaso.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
   requestPermission();
                        client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(UltimoPaso.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
       if(location != null){
          latitude_string = (String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
          longitude_string = (String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATOS: " + location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
     }
});

.... despues del create

private void requestPermission(){
        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1 ;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UltimoPaso.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            return;
        }
    }
```

El problema como les comente es que no me pregunta si tengo o no habilitado el permiso por lo tanto no me habilita la "ubicación" y los valores de `latitude_string` y `longitude_string` están siempre null, en cambio si lo habilito a mano el código funciona bien.

Comment: Estas usando mapas para la localizacion?

Comment: En este caso no, en otra pagina si, pero en esta no, es simplemente activar el Location para poder guardar la Latitud y Longitud en donde está parado el usuario en ese momento

Comment: GRACIAS por responder

Answer (score 0):

Coge el servicio de localización (LocationManager) con `getSystemService` y llama el método `isProviderEnabled` que te devolverá si el GPS esta activado o no.
Si no esta activado puedes mostrar un dialogo para lanzar un `Intent` para que el usuario lo active manualmente.

Puedes usar este código antes de abrir la `Activity` donde requieras el servicio de localización o pon tu código dentro del `else`.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (locationManager != null) {

    boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGpsEnabled) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Acivar GPS para continuar");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Activar", (d, which) -> {
            Intent intentGPS = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intentGPS);
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("No", (d, which) -> d.dismiss());
        dialog.show();
    } else {
    //tu codigo
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿podrías explicar el código para que sea útil a otros?

Comment: El código anterior que tenía era de GPS, que es con el que estoy tratando de trabajar ahora, tengo otra versión que la que ud me manda, pero la provaré a ver que tal funciona. Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

Tu código parece estar correcto pero de acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> El problema como les comente es que no me pregunta si tengo o no
>   habilitado el permiso por lo tanto no me habilita la "ubicacion"

El problema puede deberse a estas causas:

-Tu dispositivo tiene android 6.0 o superior que requiere la petición manual de los permisos  `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` y `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` pero no has definido en el `AndroidManifest.xml` los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**Es necesario definir los permisos en el AndroidManifest.xml para que se pueda realizar la petición manual.**

Relacionado:
[Se crashea la App antes de dar permisos (Google Maps API)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45737/se-crashea-la-app-antes-de-dar-permisos-google-maps-api)

-**El permiso ya fue configurado**, puedes revisarlo en la configuración de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-La versión del sistema operativo es menor a Android 6.0, en este caso no se mostraría la petición puesto que no se requiere pedirla manualmente.

---

Te sugiero agregar esta validación, para que solo dispositivos con `Android Marshmallow` requieran la petición manual:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      requestPermission();
}else{
   //No requiere pedir permisos manualmente.
}
```

Comment: Lo del manifiest si lo tengo, no lo puse porque es algo necesario si o si no? tengo los 2 permisos de usuario. Gracias probaré lo de Marshmallow

Comment: Tu metodo requestPermission() debe funcionar sin problema, pero se va a mostrar si u dispositivo tiene android 6.0 o mayor , que versión estas usando?